# Issue with substitution in sendgrid

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I've to send a mail with substitution using sendgrid.
I use the following code :

```
    public async Task SendConfirmationMailAsync(UserCreateViewModel model, string domain, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        string q = _encryption.EncryptText(model.Email + "|" + model.Password, _configuration["Security:EncryptionKey"]);
        string encryptdetexturl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(q);
        string url = domain + "/Device/RegisterDevice?q=" + encryptdetexturl;


        Dictionary<string, string> substitution = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        substitution.Add("-indirizzo_email-", url);

        await _emailService.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, "d-1201e63adfa04976ba9fc17212172fe9", substitution);
    }
```

that calls

```
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(ApplicationUser applicationUser, string templateId)
    {
        var apiKey = _configuration["Email:apikey"];

        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

        var from = new EmailAddress(_configuration["Email:Email"]);
        var to = new EmailAddress(applicationUser.Email);

        var substitutions = GetReplacement(applicationUser);

        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleTemplateEmail(from, to, templateId, null,substitutions);

        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

        Trace.WriteLine(msg.Serialize());
        Trace.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        Trace.WriteLine(response.Headers);
    }
```

that calls

```
    public static SendGridMessage CreateSingleTemplateEmail(
                                                    EmailAddress from,
                                                    EmailAddress to,
                                                    string templateId,
                                                    object dynamicTemplateData,
                                                    Dictionary<string, string> substitutions)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(templateId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(templateId)} is required when creating a dynamic template email.", nameof(templateId));
        }

        var msg = new SendGridMessage();
        msg.SetFrom(from);
        msg.AddTo(to);
        msg.TemplateId = templateId;

        if (dynamicTemplateData != null)
        {
            msg.SetTemplateData(dynamicTemplateData);
        }

        if (substitutions != null)
        {
            msg.AddSubstitutions(substitutions);
        }

        return msg;
    }
```

The send process alwais fails probably because in the third method I've separated dynamicTemplateData and substitutions. I have to send a message that refers to a templeate stored in sendgrid and and i haven't to pass it to the method.

The Sendgrid error is the following :

> {"from":{"email":"info@elettrone.com"},"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"yocax2@elettrone.com"}],"substitutions":{"-indirizzo_email-":"https://localhost:44391/Device/RegisterDevice?q=tnGdfw1EojMggP15KY39IWJGE9GkYWOTzMBsungIHrNJm6gzwc1r1zRpMZDH55%2fQ"}}],"template_id":"d-1201e63adfa04976ba9fc17212172fe9"}
>   BadRequest
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2019 18:06:50 GMT
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
>   Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
>   X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is the actual exception that you're getting?

Comment: @silleknarf : I get SendGrid BadRequest exception.

Comment: @mason  It is not a .NET exception but an exception that I draw from the SendGrid response.

Comment: @mason: It is a SendGrid BadRequest fail message. It dosn't send the email but the program dosn't crash.

Comment: @mason : I add it to the post.

Comment: @mason : look now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. When specifying the template ID the substitutions must be passed with the dynamicTemplateData and not with the substituctions.

Here is an example of use provided by Sendgrid at https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#with-mail-helper-class :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

namespace Example
{
  internal class Example
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
        Execute().Wait();
    }

    static async Task Execute()
    {
        var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage();
        msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User"));
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User"));
        msg.SetTemplateId("d-d42b0eea09964d1ab957c18986c01828");

        var dynamicTemplateData = new ExampleTemplateData
        {
            Subject = "Hi!",
            Name = "Example User",
            Location = new Location
            {
                City = "Birmingham",
                Country = "United Kingdom"
            }
        };

        msg.SetTemplateData(dynamicTemplateData);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private class ExampleTemplateData
    {
        [JsonProperty("subject")]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("location")]
        public Location Location { get; set; }
    }

    private class Location
    {
        [JsonProperty("city")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

In the template, for example, subject you have to refer with {{subject}}.

Hope this help.